# Что говорит Стандарт C++ про гибкие массивы?

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите, пожалуйста, допустимо ли использование гибких массивов в `C++`?

Например:

```
struct Object
{
    uint64_t ID;
    size_t Size;
    uint8_t Data[];
};
```

Comment: Нет, допустимо только для статических массивов `static uint8_t Data[]`

Comment: Дополнительно, если вопрос про С++, то зачем метка С?

Comment: Судя по https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412749/are-flexible-array-members-valid-in-c - в С++ их не завезли.

Comment: Это конструкция из С99. Активно используется в API Windows и Linux. Некоторые компиляторы поддерживают эту конструкцию и в С++ в качестве нестандартного расширения. Но с точки зрения стандарта, это неполное объявление типа (см. complete type)

Comment: В C разрешены *flexible array member*, но в C++ такая конструкция отсутствует. Чтобы обеспечить совместимость, просто устанавливают размер в единицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отвечать кратко, нет.

Так как в С выделение памяти под объект полностью лежит на разработчике и соответственно размещение объекта в ней тоже. В C++ создать объект с гибким массивом просто через **new** не выйдет. Но ни чего не мешает сделать это в C стиле.

```
struct Object {
    uint64_t ID;
    size_t Size;
    Type *Data; // с небольшим отличием
    static Object* newObj(size_t count){
         Object *s = (Object *)malloc(sizeof(Object) + count*sizeof(Type)));
         s.Size = count;
         s.Data = s + sizeof(Object);
         return s;
     }
     // ну и не забыть про free()
};
```

Но конечно этот хак очень быстро сломается при наследовании и виртуальных функциях, да и в принципе за такой код, где либо кроме just for fun я бы руки ломал))